# Use 'SELECT TOP' to generate a list of parameters for WHERE

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table like this:

```
|    date   | example_variable |
| 2013-2-22 |       cat        |
| 2013-3-22 |       dog        |
| 2013-1-22 |       ewe        |
| 2013-8-22 |       pig        |
```

What I already know how to do is:

```
SELECT
a.example_variable as V1,
b.example_variable as V2,
c.example_variable as V3, 
a.AsOfDate as 1stDate,     
b.AsOfDate as 2ndDate,
c.AsOfDate as 3rdDate
FROM <table> a, <table> b, <table> c
WHERE a.AsOfDate = '2013-1-22'
AND b.AsOfDate = '2013-2-22'
AND c.AsOfDate = '2013-3-22'
```

With an output like:

```
|   V1   |   V2   |   V3   |    1stDate   |    2ndDate   |    3rdDate   |
|  ewe   |   cat  |   dog  |  '2013-1-22' |  '2013-2-22' | '2013-3-22'  |
```

In my query above, I manually entered the three most recent dates. I would like those found automatically. It seems like I could use top, but I'm not sure how.

---

More complicated version:

I have simplified the above example. In my real world case there are multiple rows with the same date organized like this:

```
|    date   |      rank        | example_variable  |
| 2013-2-22 |      1           |       cat1        |
| 2013-2-22 |      2           |       cat2        |
| 2013-3-22 |      1           |       dog1        |
| 2013-3-22 |      2           |       dog2        |
| 2013-1-22 |      1           |       ewe1        |
| 2013-1-22 |      2           |       ewe2        |
| 2013-8-22 |      1           |       pig1        |
| 2013-8-22 |      2           |       pig2        |
```

And the query is like this:

```
SELECT
a.rank, b.rank, c.rank,
a.example_variable as V1,
b.example_variable as V2,
c.example_variable as V3, 
a.AsOfDate as 1stDate,     
b.AsOfDate as 2ndDate,
c.AsOfDate as 3rdDate
FROM <table> a, <table> b, <table> c
WHERE a.rank = b.rank,
And b.rank = c.rank,
AND a.AsOfDate = '2013-1-22'
AND b.AsOfDate = '2013-2-22'
AND c.AsOfDate = '2013-3-22'
```

With output:

```
|  rank  |   V1    |   V2    |   V3    |    1stDate   |    2ndDate   |    3rdDate   |
|   1    |  ewe1   |   cat1  |   dog1  |  '2013-1-22' |  '2013-2-22' | '2013-3-22'  |
|   2    |  ewe2   |   cat2  |   dog2  |  '2013-1-22' |  '2013-2-22' | '2013-3-22'  |
```

Comment: I am using Azure SQL. However, I would very much prefer clarity and simplicity over performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit 1: even with your more complicated version of the data you should be able to still use `row_number()`:

```
select [rank],
  max(case when rn = 1 then example_variable end) as v1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then example_variable end) as v2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then example_variable end) as v3,
  max(case when rn = 1 then date end) as [1stDate],
  max(case when rn = 2 then date end) as [2ndDate],
  max(case when rn = 3 then date end) as [3rdDate]
from
(
  select date, [rank], example_variable,
    row_number() over(partition by [rank] order by date) rn
  from yt
) d
group by [rank];
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48813/3)

And if you don't have `row_number` you can use the following:

```
;with d1 as
(
  select t.date, t.[rank], t.example_variable
  from yt t
  inner join
  (
    select min(date) date, [rank]
    from yt
    group by [rank]
  ) d
    on t.date = d.date
    and t.[rank] = d.[rank]
)
select d1.rank,
  d1.example_variable v1,
  d2.example_variable v2,
  d3.example_variable v3,
  d1.date [1stDate],
  d2.date [2ndDate],
  d3.date [3rdDate]
from d1
cross apply
(
  select top 1 date, [rank], example_variable
  from yt t
  where d1.date < t.date
    and d1.[rank] = t.[rank]
) d2
cross apply
(
  select top 1 date, [rank], example_variable
  from yt t
  where d2.date < t.date
    and d2.[rank] = t.[rank]
) d3;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c8de/9)

You did not specify what database you are using but if you are using a database that supports windowing functions, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select 
  max(case when rn = 1 then example_variable end) as v1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then example_variable end) as v2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then example_variable end) as v3,
  max(case when rn = 1 then date end) as [1stDate],
  max(case when rn = 2 then date end) as [2ndDate],
  max(case when rn = 3 then date end) as [3rdDate]
from
(
  select date, example_variable,
    row_number() over(order by date) rn
  from yt
) d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf88/2).

If you do not have `row_number` then you could use the following:

```
select d1.example_variable v1,
  d2.example_variable v2,
  d3.example_variable v3,
  d1.date [1stdate],
  d2.date [2nddate],
  d3.date [3rddate]
from
(
  select top 1 date, example_variable
  from yt
  order by date
) d1
cross apply
(
  select top 1 d2.date, d2.example_variable
  from yt d2
  where d1.date < d2.date
  order by d2.date
) d2
cross apply
(
  select top 1 d3.date, d3.example_variable
  from yt d3
  where d2.date < d3.date
  order by d3.date
) d3;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf88/16)

Comment: It seems to me that SQL Azure does not support windowing/window functions.

Comment: @user1744318 This link shows that it is supported -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336248.aspx#ranking

Comment: @user1744318 See my edit, I added a version without `row_number`

Comment: Would you mind putting the second one in its own answer? For my situation, the second one is very much preferred. The first one creates a lot more work for me as my real world example has complications not present in my example. Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm being weird.

Comment: @user1744318 I actually prefer to leave them in the same answer because they are both solutions to your problem.  You can still accept even if one was preferred over the other. :)

Comment: Upon further consideration, I don't think either of these are able to accomplish what I am trying to do. Modifying the WHERE in my example would really be ideal. Maybe I need to add more details to explain why this is the case, but I don't think those details are actually essential to produce a solution.

Comment: @user1744318 You should be able to easily select the top 3 dates but the problem that you are going to have is you want this data spread across 6 columns. You have to be able to pivot it using some value, if these queries don't do what you expect then you should edit your OP with correct details to answer the question.

Comment: @user1744318 See my edit, even with your more complicated data you can still get the result with these queries.

Comment: It seems that I can indeed use row_number(). However, I don't yet understand the code. Additionally, I now see I wrote my examples incorrectly because I wanted the most recent dates: '2013-8-22', '2013-3-22', and '2013-2-22'.

Comment: @user1744318 Then you would change the `row_number` code to order by desc -- `row_number() over(partition by [rank] order by date desc)` will return the most recent dates

Comment: Ah. I see I can just add a DESC after the order by parameter; great! SQL Fiddle is spiffy. Thanks for the help!